# Automatically set status field for data that has versions

Tags: sql-server

I am new to SQL Server.  I'm using SQL Server in Azure, and I am looking for the best way to accomplish setting a status field when a new record is entered.

I have the following data:

[image]

I need to set\calculate the Quote_Status field.

1. When a new version is added, the new version's Quote_Status should be "Open"
2. For the previous version (or all other versions), Quote_Status should be "Versioned"

A new version is defined as Quote_System, Quote_Date, and Quote_ID are all equal.

When a new version is added, the Quote_Status should look like this:
[image]

I've considered triggers and calculated fields, but I've never done anything like this and don't know how to start the SQL.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the column can be calculated on the fly, something like the following could work:

```
with cte as (
   select *, 
      row_number() over (
         partition by Quote_System, Quote_Date, Quote_ID 
         order by QuoteVersion desc
      ) as rn
   from dbo.yourTable
)
select *, case when rn = 1 then 'Open' else 'Versioned' end as Quote_Status
from cte;
```

Essentially, for each grouping of (Quote_System, Quote_Date, Quote_ID), I'm enumerating the versions in descending order. With that, the first (i.e. `rn = 1`) is the Open one while the rest are Versioned. In actual use, I'd add a where clause to the actual select so that there's a reasonable chance for it performing well.

If you need it to be persisted and Quote_Version is monotone increasing, I'd prefer to do it in a stored procedure. Like so:

```
create procedure dbo.insert_Quote (
    @Quote_System varchar(20), 
    @Quote_Date date,
    @Quote_ID varchar(20),
    @Quote_Version int
)
as
begin
    update dbo.yourTable
    set Quote_Status = 'Versioned'
    where Quote_System = @Quote_System
        and Quote_Date = @Quote_Date
        and Quote_ID = @Quote_ID
        and Quote_Status <> 'Versioned';

    insert into dbo.yourTable
        (Quote_System, Quote_Date, Quote_ID, Quote_Version, Quote_Status)
    values
        (@Quote_System, @Quote_Date, @Quote_ID, @Quote_Version, 'Open');
end
```

If you really need a trigger, I can come up with something like that, too. But it's my least preferable solution.